# Why only some of the target groups are healthy in an Istio Gateway NLB setup on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio, istio-gateway

The internal NLB has been provisioned by Istion Gateway and there are 5 target groups in total - 2 targets are unhealthy and 3 targets are healthy. The targets are the same nodes, only ports are different. There are 3 nodes in this EKS cluster which has a private endpoint only.

I have deployed a test application and I can reach it via the NLB load balancer. I have tested allowing all traffic in the security groups so that's not the issue.

Here is the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal":"true","service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type":"nlb"},"labels":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway","install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource":"unknown","istio":"ingressgateway","istio.io/rev":"default","operator.istio.io/component":"IngressGateways","release":"istio"},"name":"istio-ingressgateway","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"status-port","port":15021,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":15021},{"name":"http2","port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8080},{"name":"https","port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8443},{"name":"tcp","port":31400,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":31400},{"name":"tls","port":15443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":15443}],"selector":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway","istio":"ingressgateway"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-02T20:14:56Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    istio: ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    release: istio
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "3210690"
  uid: 0a63cd30-21cf-4a55-97a1-ea59b6b10e18
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.20.19.31
  clusterIPs:
  - 172.20.19.31
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 32530
    port: 15021
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15021
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 31151
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31758
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: tcp
    nodePort: 31589
    port: 31400
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 31400
  - name: tls
    nodePort: 31038
    port: 15443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15443
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

These first two have healthy targets:

```
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 32530
    port: 15021
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15021
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 31151
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

Also, here are the endpoints:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  annotations:
    endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: "2022-06-02T20:15:02Z"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-02T20:14:56Z"
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    istio: ingressgateway
    istio.io/rev: default
    operator.istio.io/component: IngressGateways
    release: istio
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "3210721"
  uid: ddd67f5b-42c6-4ab5-bb42-1d7576fdio
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.0.1.22
    nodeName: ip-10-20-21-211.eu-west-1.compute.internal
    targetRef:
      kind: Pod
      name: istio-ingressgateway-86bc5ff59d-pd6jz
      namespace: istio-system
      resourceVersion: "3210719"
      uid: 14027349-388f-4125-8b01-83656ffff54546
  ports:
  - name: tls
    port: 15443
    protocol: TCP
  - name: status-port
    port: 15021
    protocol: TCP
  - name: tcp
    port: 31400
    protocol: TCP
  - name: http2
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
```

Any suggestions on what I should check/try?

Comment: Thanks for the vote down. It would be more productive to add a comment as to why my question is not interesting.

Comment: Are you using the aws-load-balancer-controller?

Comment: @jordanm that's correct, I am using aws-load-balancer-controller.

Comment: I believe the reason the target group for port 15021 is healthy is due to it being Istio health check. The target group for port 80 is healthy due to an application that runs on port 80.